# Is there a way to simplify my deep string of "if" statements? None of them actually repeat they are all just similar

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, if-statement, data-manipulation

I have written some code to help with my GCSE revision (exams in the UK taken at age 16) which converts a string into just the first letter of every word but leaves everything else in tact. (i.e special characters at the ends of words, capitalisation, etc...)

**For example:**

If I input `>>> "These are some words (now they're in brackets!)"`

I would want it to output `>>> "T a s w (n t i b!)"`

I feel although there must be an easier way to do this than my string of similar "if" statements... For reference, I am reasonably new to python but I can't see to find an answer online. Thanks in advance!

Code:

```python
    line = input("What text would you like to memorise?\n")
words = line.split()
letters=''

spec_chars=[
    '(',')',',','.','“','”','"',"‘","’","'",'!','¡','?','¿','…'
]

for word in words:
    if word[0] in spec_chars:
        if word[-1] in spec_chars:
            if word[-2] in spec_chars:
                if word[1] in spec_chars:
                    letters += word[0] + word[1] + word[2] + word[-2] + word[-1] + " "
                else:
                    letters += word[0] + word[1] + word[-2] + word[-1] + " "
            else:
                if word[1] in spec_chars:
                    letters += word[0] + word[1] + word[2] + word[-1] + " "
                else:
                    letters += word[0] + word[1] + word[-1] + " "
        else:
            if word[1] in spec_chars:
                letters += word[0] + word[1] + word[2] + " "
            else:
                letters += word[0] + word[1] + " "
    else:
        if word[-1] in spec_chars:
            if word[-2] in spec_chars:
                letters += word[0] + word[-2] + word[-1] + " "
            else:
                letters += word[0] + word[-1] + " "
        else:
            letters += word[0] + " "

output=("".join(letters))
    print(output)
```

Comment: What about `"The kids' favourite teacher"` – would that become `"T k f t"` or `"T k' f t"`?

Comment: The latter, which is what I want, as I want the code as an aid for memorising long passages in Spanish and English Lit!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one alternative.  We keep every punctuation except apostrophe, and we only keep the first letter encountered.

```
words = "These are some words (now they're in brackets!)"
alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzé'"

output = []
for word in words.split():
    output.append( '' )
    found = False
    for i in word:
        if i in alphabet:
            if not found:
                found = True
                output[-1] += i
        else:
            output[-1] += i
print(' '.join(output))
```

Output:

```
T a s w (n t i b!)
```

Comment: Thanks! do you mind roughly explaining how the code works? Also, how would I add back the quote mark (") because it is quite important in my use case... Also, you're code keeps characters such as "é" whereas I don't want these to be considered a special character as I use this to learn Spanish alot...

Comment: I edited the code to this `words = "¿Qué es lo mejor asignatura? '(¡No es dibujo!!)'"` and it printed "¿Qé e l m a? '(¡ e d!!)" instead of "¿Q e l m a? '(¡n e d!!)'. Why is this?

Comment: You can see why this happened, right?  I have two classes of characters: One had A-Z a-z and apostrophe, the other is everything else.  I keep everything that is not in that list, but only the first from that list.  Your `é` is not in my list, so I treated it like punctuation.  If you want to extend the alphabet, then you might need to create a string of your alphabet and use `if i in alphabet:`.

Comment: I changed the code to use the "alphabet" concept.  If you find other letters that should be treated that way, just add them to the alphabet.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Sorry if I've been a little stupid I get intimidated by heaps of new code lol

Answer (score 1):

This might be somewhat overwhelming for now, but I'd still like to point out a solution that allows for a much more concise solution using regular expressions, because it's quite instructional in terms of how to approach problems like this.

**TL;DR:** It can be done in one line

```py
import re
' '.join(re.sub(r"(\w)[\w']*\w", r'\1', word) for word in text.split())
```

If you look at the words individually after using `.split()`, it appears that what you need to do is basically remove all letters (and word-internal apostrophe) after the first letter occurring in each word.

```py
[
 '"These', # remove 'hese'
 'are',    # 're'
 'some',   # 'ome'
 'words',  # 'ords'
 '(now',   # 'ow'
 "they're", # "hey're"
 'in',      # 'n'
 'brackets!)"' # 'rackets'
]
```

Another way to think about it is to find sequences consisting of

1. A letter `x`
2. A sequence of 1 or more letters

and replace the sequence with `x`. E.g., in `'"These'`, replace `'These'` with `'T'`. to arrive at `'"T'`; in `brackets!)"`, replace `'brackets'` with `'b'`, etc.

In regular expression syntax, this becomes:

1. `(\w)`: A letter is matched by `\w`, but we want to reference to it later, so we need to put it in a *group* - hence the parentheses.
2. A sequence of 1 or more (indicated by `+`) letters is `\w+`. We also want to include apostrophe, so we want a *class* indicated by `[]`, i.e., `[\w']+`, which means "match one or more instances of a letter or apostrophe".

To replace/substitute substrings matched by the pattern we use `re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)`. In the replacement string we can tell it to insert the group we defined before by using the reference `\1`.

Putting it all together:

```py
# import the re module
import re

# define the regular expression
pattern = r"(\w)[\w']+"

# some test data
texts = ["\"These are some words (now they're in brackets!)\"",
         "¿Qué es lo mejor asignatura? '(¡No es dibujo!!)'",
         "The kids' favourite teacher"]

# testing the pattern
for text in texts:
    words = text.split() 
    print(text)
    print(' '.join(re.sub(pattern, r'\1', word) for word in words))
    print()
```

Result:

```
"These are some words (now they're in brackets!)"
"T a s w (n t i b!)"

¿Qué es lo mejor asignatura? '(¡No es dibujo!!)'
¿Q e l m a? '(¡N e d!!)'

The kids' favourite teacher
T k f t
```

To include word-final apostrophe, modify the pattern to

```py
pattern = r"(\w)[\w']*\w"
```

so that the letter-apostrophe sequence *must* end with a letter.
In other words, we now match

1. a group consisting of a letter `(\w)`, followed by
2. zero or more (indicated by `*`) instances of letter or apostrophe, and
3. a letter `\w`.

The result is exactly the same as above, except the last sentence becomes "T k' f t".

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working fine for me.

Here, I am just checking the left and right end of each word of the given sentence.

Let me know in case of any clarification.

```
words = "¿Qué es lo mejor asignatura? '(¡No es dibujo!!)'"
spec_chars = ['(', ')', ',', '.', '“', '”', '"', "‘",
              "’", "'", '!', '¡', '?', '¿', '…']
s_lst = words.split(' ')
tmp, rev_tmp = '', ''
for i in range(len(s_lst)):
    for l in s_lst[i]:
        if l in spec_chars:
            tmp += l
        else:
            tmp += l
            for j in s_lst[i][::-1]:
                if j in spec_chars:
                    rev_tmp += j
                else:
                    tmp += rev_tmp[::-1]
                    break
            s_lst[i] = tmp
            tmp = ''
            rev_tmp = ''
            break
print(' '.join(s_lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you are at an entry-level, you can use a for loop to simplify your if statement. It is not perfect but could solve the question you have raised.`

```
line = input("What text would you like to memorise?\n")
words = line.split()
spec_chars=['(',')',',','.','“','”','"',"‘","’","'",'!','¡','?','¿','…']
letters=''

for word in words:
    letters+=word[0]
    if word[0] in spec_chars:
        letters+=word[1]
    elif word[-2] in spec_chars:
        letters+=word[-2]+word[-1]
    elif word[-1] in spec_chars:
        letters+=word[-1]

print(letters)
```